# Component package type?

Tags: identification, surface-mount

I’ve been fixing Chromebook laptop. It slow power charging at first and then it won’t charge at all and it smell burnt
and then I found short on this component.

But I can’t determine what is it is. I searched the marking and doesn’t find any information about it.

Anyone know what this component is?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It'd help to see more context.

Comment: Did it used to be one component and now it’s burned off into two? Take more photos, then desolder the remains and trace out the circuit around it?

Comment: @winny no its two identical component. And it burn the bottom one

Comment: It looks to be connecting a data line to ground, so it's probably either a capacitor as part of a signal conditioning network or a protection device like a TVS diode. I can't give more information than that without a lot more data and measurements on the non-broken device.

Comment: Ah! That’s a better situation. Ideally, find the schematic and BOM. Second option would be to find a broken laptop, hope the board revision is the same or similar enough and lift the working component from that one.

Comment: These packages are sometimes called DFN, they look like protection diodes but be mindful I’ve met transistors in a 3 pin DFN of the same size. Might wanna blow off the dead one and check the land.

Comment: @Bryan i desolder that bottom components and Its two pin. And also the upper one get burned after i try to charge without the bottom ic

Comment: @JulianMustofa repair of the device would be put the scope of your question here, and to get good repair advice you must do a lot of work tracing the circuit and it’s operation. I will say that these looks like protection diodes on differential data lines and probably far removed from charging systems, and if they’re blowing there might be some serious voltage regulation issues and other blown chips on this board.